# Getting weird supervisor error on github repo

Tags: elixir

I am brand new to Elixir and am having a really hard time tracking down issues when a build decides not to build.

So I am trying to use this [repo](https://github.com/chvanikoff/reph2) based on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@chvanikoff/phoenix-react-love-story-reph-2-14a6dcadbbd0#.oi3cnbira)

One of the issues that I am having is that I continually get this issue:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application reph: Reph.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Reph.ReactIO
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (ArgumentError) expected :name option to be one of:

  * nil
  * atom
  * {:global, term}
  * {:via, module, term}

Got: {:local, Reph.ReactIO}

            (elixir) lib/supervisor.ex:332: Supervisor.start_link/3
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:365: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:348: :supervisor.start_children/3
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:314: :supervisor.init_children/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

So I did some investigating in the elixir [codebase](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/gen_server.ex) to see what that argument was.  It looks to me like StdJsonIo should still compile correctly with the

```
{atom, opts} when is_atom(atom) ->
    :gen.start(:gen_server, link, {:local, atom}, module, args, opts)
```

Snippet in the Supervisor as I am passing the atom :local followed by the Module.  Here is the code snippet it looks to be hanging up on.

```
def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: {:local, __MODULE__})
end
```

If I remove the :local it seems to work, but then I have two problems, one is the code seems to error out completely with another issue, the other is.  Now I have a dependency that I can't just pull with deps.get and run I have to add it separately which might be ok.  But I'd really like to know why that breaks the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you could see in the source code, [`Supervisor.start_link/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/supervisor.ex#L321) expects the options values to be one of those you got in the descriptive error message.

That said, `name` option can’t have a value `{:local, __MODULE__}`. You could go with `name: __MODULE__` which is sufficient in many cases, or you might pass any `atom` there instead of `__MODULE__` (which is compiled to the currently compiling module name.)

What you were referring as “Elixir codebase” is a method `do_start` which is apparently not what you are calling. Whether you want `do_start` to be called, start your `GenServer` with [`GenServer.start/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#start/3), which is intended to start servers *outside of the supervision tree*.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I was looking in the wrong file.  I feel like a dult thanks very much.

Comment: Everybody sometimes looks at the wrong files :) Welcome.

Comment: Uff :) I was looking for a solution based on your explanation. But I couldn't find any. Could any of you provide a working example, please? :) thanks so much!

Comment: @mudasobwa how the code finally has to look like.
https://gist.github.com/radosch/b1f0fc47bb0c36bdff642744b223cb18
How should one call the supervisor, so that it can be started?

Comment: From what I see you use `Phoenix`. In most cases, one should not start supervisors manually. Just put them into the tree as you do. `workers` are supervised by `supervisor`s and the whole tree is managed by OTP transparently.

Comment: I am still not sure, from your answer I conclude, that I have to adjust the Module itself and cannot e.g. configure through the startup process.

Comment: @radosch I am not sure I follow. Would you mind to just post a separate question with detailed description, rather that commenting the more-or-less unrelated post?